# How to set up Binding of computed value inside class (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, class, object, binding

In my Model I have an array of Items, and a computed property `proxy` which using set{} and get{} to set and return currently selected item inside array and works as shortcut. Setting item's value manually as `model.proxy?.value = 10` works, but can't figure out how to Bind this value to a component using $.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item {
    var value: Double
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = [Item(value: 1), Item(value: 2), Item(value: 3)]
    
    var proxy: Item? {
        get {
            return items[1]
        }
        set {
            items[1] = newValue!
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Value: \(model.proxy!.value)")
            
            Button(action: {model.proxy?.value = 123}, label: {Text("123")}) // method 1: this works fine
            SubView(value: $model.proxy.value) // method 2: binding won't work
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct SubView <B:BinaryFloatingPoint> : View {
    @Binding var value: B
    var body: some View {
        Button( action: {value = 100}, label: {Text("1")})
    }
}
```

Is there a way to modify `proxy` so it would be modifiable and bindable so both methods would be available?

Thanks!

**Day 2: Binding**

Thanks to George, I have managed to set up Binding, but the desired binding with `SubView` still won't work. Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item {
    var value: Double
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = [Item(value: 0), Item(value: 0), Item(value: 0)]
    
    var proxy: Binding <Item?> {
        Binding <Item?> (
            get: { self.items[1] },
            set: { self.items[1] = $0! }
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    @State var myval: Double = 10
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Value: \(model.proxy.wrappedValue!.value)")
            Button(action: {model.proxy.wrappedValue?.value = 555}, label: {Text("555")})
            SubView(value: model.proxy.value) // this still wont work
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct SubView <T:BinaryFloatingPoint> : View {
    @Binding var value: T
    var body: some View {
        Button( action: {value = 100}, label: {Text("B 100")})
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all I don't understand why the binding is optional since you are using a hardcoded index so you will either always get an object or you will always get a crash. Secondly since your sub view is generic you need to pass the type, `SubView<Double>(value: model.proxy.value)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson index is barcoded for sake of making sample code shorter. As for Double I'm trying to make a component that accepts CGFloat, Double, and Int, so im using BinaryFloatingPoint. But not sure how to deal with BinaryFloatingPoint quite yet.

Comment: Ok but did you try my code? For me this works.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Binding` instead.

Example:

```
var proxy: Binding<Item?> {
    Binding<Item?>(
        get: { items[1] },
        set: { items[1] = $0! }
    )
}
```